# SELECT JOIN duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I've database with 3 tables like:

services

```
   id | name | service_id (UNIQUE)
    1  | new  |    123
    2  | service1  |    543
```

counts

```
   id | counts | counts_price | service_id
    1  | 100    |     200      | 123
    5  | 200    |     250      | 123
    6  | 300    |     350      | 543
```

background

```
   id | background | background_price | service_id
    1  |   white    |        50        | 123
   12  |   red      |        150        | 123
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT background.background, services.name, counts.count 
FROM services INNER JOIN background 
ON background.service_id=services.service_id INNER JOIN counts 
ON counts.service_id=services.service_id 
WHERE services.service_id = :service_id
```

:service_id = 123
In output I got
    [var_dump](http://pastebin.com/CeL6m8tp)

Why it's duplicated? What's wrong with query?

```
<pre>
 array (size=4)
 0 => 
 array (size=3)
  0 => string 'white' (length=5)
  1 => string 'new' (length=3)
  2 => string '200' (length=3)
 1 => 
 array (size=3)
  0 => string 'red' (length=3)
  1 => string 'new' (length=3)
  2 => string '200' (length=3)
 2 => 
 array (size=3)
  0 => string 'white' (length=5)
  1 => string 'new' (length=3)
  2 => string '250' (length=3)
 3 => 
 array (size=3)
  0 => string 'red' (length=3)
  1 => string 'new' (length=3)
  2 => string '250' (length=3)
</pre>
```

Comment: No links, post the picture here. Anyway, just add `DISTINCT` to the beginning of the `SELECT`

Comment: I've tried `DISTINCT` before, doesn't works.

Comment: It is not duplicated. You have what you want it to have in your SQL statement. You got 4 values . Look that your counts are different for white and red values.

With this query and this db data you have it is all fine. What u want to get ?

Comment: just tell what output you want

Comment: Oh, I get it. This same service_id value. Is any way to get  
    [this](http://pastebin.com/aX2yd8Av)
instead var_dump before?

Answer (score 1):

Add `group by` for this.

```
GROUP BY services.service_id
```

So your final query would be:

```
SELECT background.background, services.name, counts.count, services.service_id 
FROM services INNER JOIN background 
ON background.service_id=services.service_id INNER JOIN counts 
ON counts.service_id=services.service_id 
WHERE services.service_id = :service_id
GROUP BY services.service_id
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but If I'll add `GROUP BY` I got only one field in array.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I need output: white, new 200; red, new, 250

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your data does not know which backgrounds are associated with which counts. In this simple example you could generate row numbers to assist something like this -

```
select  t.background
         ,se.name
         ,s.counts_price
from
(
select c.*,
            if(c.service_id<> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rownumber,
            @p:=c.service_id p
from    (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) rn,counts c
order   by c.service_id,c.id
) s
join
(
select b.*,
            if(b.service_id<> @p1, @rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rownumber1,
            @p1:=b.service_id p
from    (select @rn1:=0,@p1:=0) rn,background b
order   by b.service_id,b.id
) t on t.service_id = s.service_id and t.rownumber1 = s.rownumber

join services se on se.service_id = s.service_id
```

Result

```
+------------+------+--------------+
| background | name | counts_price |
+------------+------+--------------+
| white      | new  |          200 |
| red        | new  |          250 |
+------------+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your out put

```
 SELECT background.background, services.name, counts.count 
 FROM services INNER JOIN background 
 ON background.service_id=services.service_id INNER JOIN counts 
 ON counts.service_id=background.service_id AND counts.id != background.id
 WHERE services.service_id = 123
```

Hope it work as you need